# Can't read one random radiobutton in a PDF using iTextSharp in an ASP.NET / C# Application

Tags: c#, asp.net, pdf, itext

i am having a strange issue, i can read all the controls, their values inside a pdf along with assigning them the new values, except one. There are 15 radiobutton groups in the pdf while the code just reads 14 and one radiobutton is skipped. Has this sort of thing happened to anyone else?

My code looks like this

```
 AcroFields reader_fields = pdfReader.AcroFields;
            foreach (DictionaryEntry de in pdfReader.AcroFields.Fields)
            {
                int field_type = reader_fields.GetFieldType(de.Key.ToString());
                string fieldTypeDesc = field_type == 2 ? "Checkbox" : field_type == 3 ? "Radiobutton" : field_type == 4 ? "Text" : field_type == 6 ? "Combo" : "Off";
                sbValues.Append(de.Key.ToString() + " - " + fieldTypeDesc + "<br />");
            }
```

Moreover i am using itextSharp version 4.1.6.0

**Edit**

Link to the PDF file

[Sample PDF](http://www.filedropper.com/showdownload.php/work-capacity-certificate)

Problematic radiobutton group has title **Memory (short term and/or long term)**

Comment: Your question can't be answered if you don't share the PDF.

Comment: Hi Bruno i have edited my original post. Kindly have a look into it. Thanks

Comment: That's an old version of iTextSharp.

Comment: Yes it is, but all other radiobutton groups are accessible, hence i don't think version is the issue over here.

Comment: @HjD But if we help you out, you'll keep on using iTextSharp 4.1.6.0 and we want to protect you against the problems explained here: http://developers.itextpdf.com/question/can-itext-217-or-earlier-be-used-commercially I hope you understand the dilemma you are confronting us with. If we help you, you'll do something you shouldn't do (making us an accomplice). If we don't help you, you'll search for an alternative (and we're not an accomplice).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every field in a PDF that has the same name is considered to be the same field, regardless of page placement. In your case, you are using a field called `Group12` on both page 1 and page 2. On page 1 this field corresponds to *The injusy(s)/conditions...* and on page 2 this field corresponds to *Memory (short term and/or long term)*. If you try to fill this form out in something like Adobe Reader you'll see that checking a radio on one page *unchecks* it from the other which you almost definitely do not want.

Comment: Hey Chris, 

Thanks for pointing that out. I have been trying to access them separately with the help of different forms that they are present in, but unfortunately i haven't been able to get to them. Can you guide me how to either access them individually or change name for one of the fields so that i can access it accordingly. Thanks.

Comment: Do you have Adobe Acrobat Professional or some other desktop publishing software? If so, I'd just use that to make the change and be done with it. Ultimately you need to delete one of the two annotations and create a new one with a new unique name. Adobe will make this transparent to you by just allowing you to "rename" one of them. If you inspect the actual PDF you'll see that form fields are stored outside of the page stream so there's no way to differentiate between pages. The values you chose, however, _happen_ to be unique per page so you could use that. `Yes, No, Choice1, 2 and 3`.

Comment: Well in the end i used acrobat reader to re assign field names and their possible acceptable values to make the code generic. Thanks Chris for your helpful insight.